# MongoDB - Export - export all the documents matching the specific field - that are listed in a file

Tags: mongodb, export

Ex: Document structure

```
{
 code : "ABC",
 ...
}
```

I have to export all the documents matching the code - that are listed in a file

fetchlist.txt

```
ABC
XYZ
PRQ
```

What is the best way to export documents matching the code in to a json file.

As of now i getting the documents using java mongodb client. Is there any better way to do it directly using mongo utilities like mongodb shell script, mongoexport itself

Comment: As of now i getting the documents using java mongodb client. Is there any better way to do it directly using mongo utilities like mongodb shell script, mongoexport itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Mongo Shell (JavaScript) and the inbuilt [`cat` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cat/) to read the file and then do a query using the [`$in` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).

If you want to export the result to a file, you need to store the following code in a `script.js` file:

```js
// read the file contents
var file = cat('fetchlist.txt')

// each code is in a separate line, so split by newline (\n)
var codes = file.split('\n')

// use $in operator to get all documents matching one of the codes
var res = db.collection.find({ code: { $in: codes } })

// print json
printjson(res.toArray())
```

Then you can execute the following command:

```sh
mongo mongodb://url script.js > result.json
```

And your matching documents will be saved in `result.json`.

Comment: @karnaa you're welcome - and welcome to stackoverflow!